# Why does React see the old state in this example?

Tags: reactjs

Here's a component that displays a number (initially 0) and a button that when clicked increments that number. If the number is 10, it also displays a celebratory message.

```
function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const [milestone, setMilestone] = React.useState(false);

  const increment = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
    if (count === 10) {
      setMilestone(true);
    } else {
      setMilestone(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{count}</h1>
      <button onClick={increment}>+1</button>
      {milestone ? <h1>Happy aniversary!</h1> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I display this, very confusingly, the "Happy anniversary!" message displays when the number on display is *eleven*, and I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `count` is ten only on the eleventh click.

you can change your increment function to:

```
const increment = () => {
    const newCount = count + 1
    setCount(newCount);
    setMilestone(newCount === 10);
};
```

Or may be use `setMilestone` within a `React.useEffect`, like:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  setMilestone(count === 10);
}, [count])
```